# Escreva uma função que retorne o maior de dois números passados como argumentos

Tags: python-3.x

Queria fazer essa função pegando a entrada do teclado mas não estou conseguindo.

```
def bigger(a, b):
  a = input('informe um valor: ')
  b = input('Informe outro valor: ')
  if a > b:
     print('O valor a é maior',a)
  else:
     print('O valor b é maior',b)
bigger()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
def bigger():
    a = int(input('informe um valor: '))
    b = int(input('Informe outro valor: '))
    if a > b:
        print('O valor a é maior',a)
    else:
        print('O valor b é maior',b)

bigger()
```

Note que eu removi os parâmetros passados, visto que tu vai inserir eles por `input` dentro da função.

Note também que estou forçando o tipo de dado para `int`, o mesmo pode ser feito para `float`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante

Answer (score 0):

Você não está passando os parâmetros requisitados na chamada da função, e mesmo que fizesse isso estaria comparando texto pois o input retorna uma string.

O que você deve fazer é ler os inputs no escopo principal, convertê-los para inteiros e passar os inputs para a função.

```
def bigger(a, b):
  if a > b:
     print('O valor a é maior', a)
  else:
     print('O valor b é maior', b)

a = int(input('informe um valor: '))
b = int(input('Informe outro valor: '))

bigger(a, b)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela observação e pela resposta, serviu de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para fins de boas prática, vou adicionar esta resposta.

O ideal seria receber a entrada, processá-la e imprimir o resultado em funções ou lugares diferentes. Mas como o seu código é pequeno, não é necessária nenhuma outra função.

```py
def bigger(a, b):
  if a > b:
     return 'O valor a é maior: %s' % a
  else:
     return 'O valor b é maior: %s' % b

a = float(input('informe um valor: '))
b = float(input('Informe outro valor: '))

print( bigger(a, b) )
```